# Assign points to another point layer's value

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2

ArcMap 10.2 with extensions ArcScan and Spatial Analyst. 
I have two point layers (A and B). A has about 40 points and each point has a value (max. number of people it can hold). B has about 1000 points (every point is a person). 
I want to assign B (people) to A's max. number so that I can tell if there is enough capacity in all A-points for all the people on my map.
How do I do this, do I need to convert it to raster data or can I just do an analysis with the point data?
(I haven't been using GIS for a few years so I'm a bit rusty. I hope this question isn't too stupid.)

Comment: Do you have a specific search radius that each A point covers, or can any B go to all A?

Comment: B can go to all A

Comment: Sum all the max values in A and see if it adds up to the number of B points. In that case, this isn't really a spatially related problem :)

Comment: Yes, I thought of that too, but I really want it to be vizualized on a map. Can it be done if B goes to the closest A (and then to the second closest if the closest A is already full)?

Comment: And also if A has another criteria (e.g. only accepts people of certain ages), how do I implement that?

Comment: I suggest that you try to create a script tool based on Radouxju's pseudo code. If you run in to trouble along the way or need help to implement certain functions in your script later you should ask a new question about that specific problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to iterate, but there could be faster methods. However, I think that the iteration is necessary because the "closest" property will change when some points A are "full".

0) before the loop, initialize the counter to "0" and add a field in B to store the FID from A.

1) create a layer using the points in A where the field value is > than your counter

2) spatial join the points from B on the points from the layer based on the points from A

3) table join the result on the B points

4) compute the FID value of A in a field of B

5) remove the join and make a layer with points from B without a FID of A

6) increment your counter by one and iterate

You can handle additional criteria in the whereclause of your feature layer, the rest of the loop will not change.